# What do the curly braces mean in docker inspect --format "{{.State.Pid}}"?

Tags: bash, docker

I'm looking through this shell script and I'm curious what the double curly braces are doing in this line:

https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter/blob/master/docker-enter#L16

I know that curly braces in shell are used for grouping, but what does two sets of curly braces do? If someone could explain this:

```
docker inspect --format "{{.State.Pid}}"
```

I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I've tried to edit the question in such a way as to be found by folks who are curious about Docker, as folks curious about brace-based expansion syntax built into the shell aren't likely to find it to be a good use for their time.

Answer (score 7):

The context of this was a command running

```
docker inspect --format "{{.State.Pid}}"
```

The Docker option `--format` takes a go template. Double-curly-braces are meaningful in Go templates, not in bash.

See [the Go text.template package documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) for details. To quote from same:

> "Actions"--data evaluations or control structures--are delimited by "{{" and "}}"; all text outside actions is copied to the output unchanged.

Comment: TIL docker was written in GO

Comment: Can you add an example of a Go template in action? I'm having trouble understanding why the `.`s are placed the way they are.

Comment: @mbigras, if you're familiar with jq, it's very similar in this context. The template is being evaluated in the context of a struct which contains a `State` member, which is an object of a type that contains a `Pid` entry; the leading `.` refers to the cursor at starting position. *Do* see the linked documentation, which has plenty of samples included.